# Karma is possibly running the wrong group of tests- how to fix this?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner

I'm following along with the Egghead Angular.js tutorial, and trying to set up Karma to work with my toy app.

To install and configure Karma, I'm following this guide:  http://www.tuesdaydeveloper.com/2013/06/angularjs-testing-with-karma-and-jasmine/

I've installed karma (`npm install -g karma`) and run `karma init` to create the config file, and I've got a simple test set up to verify the config is correct.  Here's the test file:

```
describe('app', function() {

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    describe('sample test', function() {

        it('should fail', function() {
            expect(false).toBe(true);
        });

    });

});
```

When I run `karma run karma.conf.js` or just `karma run`, I get the following output:

```
$ karma run karma.conf.js 
[2014-11-08 15:10:41.307] [DEBUG] config - Loading config         
/Users/myname/Desktop/Workspace/Angular/Egghead/karma.conf.js
LOG: 'all tests loaded!'
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X) LOG: LOG
'all tests loaded!'
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X): Executed 256 of 256 SUCCESS (0.679 secs / 0.404 secs)
```

I interpret this as Karma loading and running 256 tests successfully.  Since I don't have 256 tests written for this app, I think Karma is somehow running tests from another Angular app, located in a separate directory.  I had a theory that the other config file was also named 'karma.conf.js' and I was accidentally running those other tests due to a naming collision, so I created a new config named "foobar.conf.js" and ran that but got the same result.

My question is, does the above theory sound plausible, and if so how can I separate my tests so that I can run only those of the app I'm working on?

For reference, here's my config file:

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Sat Nov 08 2014 14:52:31 GMT-0800 (PST)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '/Users/myname/Desktop/Workspace/Angular/Egghead/',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      './*.js',
      './**/*.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN ||     
    config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

UPDATE: here are the contents of the app directory:

```
$ ls -la
total 48
drwxr-xr-x   7 richiethomas  staff   238 Nov  8 16:04 .
drwxr-xr-x  20 richiethomas  staff   680 Nov  8 10:32 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 richiethomas  staff  6148 Nov  8 10:33 .DS_Store
-rw-r--r--   1 richiethomas  staff   178 Nov  8 15:09 app-spec.js
-rw-r--r--   1 richiethomas  staff   499 Nov  8 14:26 app.js
-rw-r--r--   1 richiethomas  staff   822 Nov  8 14:27 index.html
-rw-r--r--   1 richiethomas  staff  1654 Nov  8 16:05 karma.conf.js
```

UPDATE: I deleted all files in the karma.conf.js `files` array except for `'./app-spec.js'`, and re-ran the tests.  Still no joy.

Comment: Could you please show how your app is structured, namely - check if the test spec files (or the containing directories) are referenced in your conf file. This `files: [
      './*.js',
      './**/*.js'
    ],` is where `karma` tries to locate tests.

Comment: I assumed that adding "./*.js" to the 'files' array would load the test file for this app, since the only specfile is in the same directory as the karma file.  But for the record, I will add the app's directory contents to the question.

Comment: Does it still run 256 tests if you move you `spec` file to a directory above?

Comment: And also, instead of using `files: [ './*.js', './**/*.js' ]` try to specify only the name of your spec file, and see what happens then

Comment: I'm confused, are you asking what happens if I move `app-spec.js` from the current directory into the parent directory?  If so, I'm not sure what the goal of that would be, can you explain your reasoning behind that suggestion?  

As per your other suggestion, I removed all files from the `files` array except for `app-spec.js`, but the output was still `Executed 256 of 256`.

Comment: Oh, what I meant is - if `app-spec.js` is the file where you have your unit test defined, then try to specify `files` object to be as follows: `files: [ 'app-spec.js' ]` and see what happens then.

Comment: Hmmm, ok I replaced `./app-spec.js` with `app-spec.js` (i.e. I removed the `./` from the beginning), but no luck.  By the way, I thought `./` was equivalent to the current directory, is that not correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64556/discussion-between-agentutah-and-nikolay-melnikov).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the following fixed the problem:

---

1) Include the following files in the karma.conf.js `files` array:

```
'angular.min.js',
'angular-mocks.js',
'app.js',
'app-spec.js'
```

2) The string '/Users/myname/Desktop/Workspace/Angular/Egghead/' in the `basepath` field was optional, tests passed whether or not I included it.

3) Looks like I left out the dependencies array inside the call to `module('myApp')` [i.e. I could have also wrote `module(myApp, [])`], but since the dependency array was empty, it made no syntactic difference in this case and the tests pass either way.

4) Run `karma start` instead of `karma run`.  This seemed to be significant for some reason.